# Architect admin interface for single page app

Tags: ember.js, architecture, single-page-application, rails-api

I have a single page app built with emberjs with an a rails backend. Is it a common pattern to build an admin interface on rails serverside on a subdomain. What is the right approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague but I will try to answer it my best. I have done this with a Node and a Go backend combined with Ember.js.

**No**, there is technically nothing to prevent you from doing a single page application for an admin interface.

Rails is a good choice for this, and generally you should stick with the backend framework/language you and your team master the most.

As for what would be the right approach, there is no magic recipes. Document your code, write test and follow best practices for the tools you are using.

One key element though will be the communication between your frontend and your backend. Ember chose to follow the JSON API specification (http://jsonapi.org/) and comes out of the box with an adapter to talk with these kind of API. Using such adapter will help you save a lot of time.
Here are some implementation of JSON API for Ruby : http://jsonapi.org/implementations/#server-libraries-ruby

One more thing about your frontend code structure. You haven't say how big your app will be. If it gets big, you may want to take the `pod` approach in ember-cli (http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#pod-structure). It basically changes the structure of the code so it's easier to maintain a lot of files.